# How to group by, aggregate by another field

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
guest2023_agg = agg_df_2023.groupby(['Country']).agg({
    'Email': 'nunique',
    'Unique Trip Count': 'sum',
    'Total Length of Stay': 'sum',
    'Total Revenue': 'sum',
    'Guest Type': [count_new_guests, count_non_new_guests, lambda x: x[x == 'New Guest']['Total Revenue'].sum()]
}).reset_index()
```

What I am trying to do with this code is to sum the revenue of only where Guest type is == to New Guest.
I am getting an error on "Total Revenue", KeyError: 'Total Revenue' I cannot understand why

Could you help?

Comment: You can't access other columns in `agg`, so you must pre-filter the date before the `groupby`

Comment: got you ... the I filter the data and merge the table ok ok thx you